# Merge a forward lstm and a backward lstm in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm

I would like to merge a forward LSTM and a backward LSTM in Keras. The input array of the backward LSTM is different from that of a forward LSTM. Thus, I cannot use keras.layers.Bidirectional.

The forward input is (10, 4). 
The backward input is (12, 4) and it is reversed before put into the model. I would like to reverse it again after LSTM and merge it with the forward.

The simplified model is as follows.

```
from lambdawithmask import Lambda as MaskLambda

def reverse_func(x, mask=None):
    return tf.reverse(x, [False, True, False])

forward = Sequential()
backward = Sequential()
model = Sequential()

forward.add(LSTM(input_shape = (10, 4), output_dim = 4, return_sequences = True))
backward.add(LSTM(input_shape = (12, 4), output_dim = 4, return_sequences = True))
backward.add(MaskLambda(function=reverse_func, mask_function=reverse_func))
model.add(Merge([forward, backward], mode = "concat", concat_axis = 1))
```

When I run this, the error message is:
Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [bool, float32] that don't all match.

Could anyone help me? I coded in Python 3.5.2 with Keras (2.0.5) and the backend is tensorflow (1.2.1).

Comment: I updated my answer, see if it helps. Feel free to comment and ask questions, show the line where the error appears and the error message. We're here to help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have two different inputs, you cannot use a Sequential model. You must use the functional API Model:

```
from keras.models import Model
```

The two first models can be sequential, no problem, but the junction must be a regular model. When it's about concatenating, I also use the functional approach (create the layer, then pass the input):

```
junction = Concatenate(axis=1)([forward.output,backward.output])
```

Why axis=1? You can only concatenate things with the same shape. Since you have 10 and 12, they're not compatible unless you use this exact axis for the merge,  which is the second axis, considering you have (BatchSize, TimeSteps, Units)

For creating the final model, use the `Model`, specify the inputs and outputs:

```
model = Model([forward.input,backward.input], junction)
```

---

In the model to be reversed, use simply a `Lambda` layer. A MaskLambda does more than just the function you want. I also suggest you use the keras backend insted of tensorflow functions:

```
import keras.backend as K

#instead of the MaskLambda:
backward.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.reverse(x,axes=[1]), output_shape=(12,?))
```

Here, the `?` is the amount of units your LSTM layers have. See PS at the end.

---

PS: I'm not sure `output_dim` is useful in the LSTM layer. It's necessary in Lambda layers, but I never use it anywhere else. Shapes are natural consequences of the amount of "units" you put in your layers. Strangely, you didn't specify the amount of units.

PS2: How exactly do you want to concatenate two sequences with different sizes?

Comment: I used a Lambda layer and the keras backend instead, and I got it. Thank you.

Comment: :) -- Would you consider marking it as a valid answer?

Answer (score 1):

As said in above answer, using a Functional API offers you much flexibility in case of multi input/output models. You can simply set the `go_backwards` argument as `True` to reverse the traversal of the input vector by the `LSTM` layer.

I have defined the `smart_merge` function below which merges the forward and backward LSTM layers together along with handling the single traversal case.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, merge

def smart_merge(vectors, **kwargs):
        return vectors[0] if len(vectors)==1 else merge(vectors, **kwargs)      

input1 = Input(shape=(10,4), dtype='int32')
input2 = Input(shape=(12,4), dtype='int32')

LtoR_LSTM = LSTM(56, return_sequences=False)
LtoR_LSTM_vector = LtoR_LSTM(input1)
RtoL_LSTM = LSTM(56, return_sequences=False, go_backwards=True)
RtoL_LSTM_vector = RtoL_LSTM(input2)

BidireLSTM_vector = [LtoR_LSTM_vector]
BidireLSTM_vector.append(RtoL_LSTM_vector)
BidireLSTM_vector= smart_merge(BidireLSTM_vector, mode='concat')
```